# Controlling variable TDP in laptops

Tags: power-management, hp

Many modern laptops come with advanced power management and the ability to dynamically change the [TDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power) (not just fiddle with frequencies and governors).
The problem is that, usually, you can change the "power profile" only using some vendor-provided Windows application.

For example I was investigating the HP Spectre x360 13 with an [i7-1065G7](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) CPU; the laptop is configured for a 18 W TDP but that can be raised to 28 W by selecting the "Performance mode" in HP's control center.

Is there any reliable way to replicate this kind of behavior in Ubuntu? Or you have to live with a power-limited computer if you want to run a non-Windows OS?

Since I've been asked I currently use Linux Mint but I'm not committed to it. I may as well switch to something different depending of different on things that are/are not supported like the topic of this question.

Comment: A clarification, when I write: "I was investigating the HP Spectre..." it means that I was investigating the Hp Spectre, non that I own one. And "For example" means for example: at this point I'm not looking for a specific solution, I'm looking for a general solution for modern intel-based laptops. I have to buy a new laptop and I want to be sure I can fully exploit it under Linux. Of course, if no general solution exists I'll start looking for device-specific ones.

Comment: That's an excellent thing to put in your question w/ [edit]. 1) Which Linux distro do you intend to use (Ubuntu server or desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) and 2) which release #?  Different versions, different tools. 3) We can't recommend specific hardware here; that's the bailiwick of http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com as per rules set down long before I arrived.  Click [edit] to add 1-2 to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, as that's our channel to you. All the issue's fact should go in the Question by [edit]

Comment: In my lenovo legion y540, I can set either quiet, balance or performance mode in windows and it saves that setting to bios and when i use linux i see the difference with max TDP of 60 watts instead of 45 Watts in balance mode.

Comment: Good to know, it would be interesting to understand if this is a common strategy or it is just a Lenovo thing.

Comment: @K7AAY that statement of yours about hardware recommendations looks weird to me. I just want to assess the level of support for specific devices, it looks quite on-topic to me.